# Must call associate() before calling activate()

Tags: jakarta-ee, error-handling, cdi

I am getting this exception when deploying an application `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must call associate() before calling activate()`, It uses CDI Named beans also I m using the `<error-page>`. when I remove the declaration of the error page from the web.xml every thing's Ok.

Thank's in advance.

Comment: which application server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Huh, Tomcat 6 and CDI - I wouldn't expect this to work at all (Servlet Spec, JSF, ...). Do you have any chance to try your setup in a recent Tomcat 7?

Answer (score 0):

There was a severe problem with Tomcat when using Weld, the implementation of CDI, and form based authentication. It has been fixed as of version 6.0.36. https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52423

It has also been fixed in Tomcat 7.0.9. https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49991

The same problem occurred with JBoss 6 and was fixed some time ago. Using Weblogic 12c, I ran into this problem also.